# Loading of Property file through spring

Tags: java, spring

I have my test.properties file in src/main/resources folder & I am loading that file  in below way in spring 3.0

```
<util:properties id="appProp" 
location="classpath:/test.properties" /> 
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="appProp"  />
```

If I changed the value in test.properties file then do I need to build project again or will it be load on server startup & reflect the changes  ?

Comment: it will load on server startup.

Comment: I tried this on local but it is not reflecting do I need to change in any other location like web.xml

Comment: did you tried same setup?

Comment: willl  the changes going to be reflect when I restart my server??